# integers in char array

Tags: c, int, printf, arrays

I want know how integers are treated in char arrays. For example when we use `scanf()` & `printf()` functions for single characters we use `"%c"`, for string values `"%s"`, etc. I used `"%s"` for printing the char array with integers. But it prints some junk characters as the output.

Comment: @UchiaItachi It's kinda vague with 'struct' , linked-lists and stuff. Basically my requirement is that, user enters a phone number>>it is assigned to a variable>> this is copied to the struct variable>> and when user wants to search a phone number for the given name, it should print the number. I cannot use int variable to get the phone number, since it starts withe the digit 0.

Comment: Maybe store the phone numbers as a strings (char arrays) instead of integer types? You can tell printf to pad an integer out with leading zeros but you'll still need to know how many leading zeros there should be.

Comment: @patmanpato yeah that's exactly what i've done. but when printing a phone number using `("%s",&num1)`, it prints some junk characters. :/

Comment: %s will expect a string, so you'll get garbage, or worse, if you give it an int. For some examples of formatting with printf: http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

Answer (score 0):

While working with integer variables directly, it's simple as:

```
int i = 7;
printf("%d", i);
```

and while working with an array of characters, you could create helper functions that will do the conversion between `char*` <-> `int` so that you end up with more portable solution:

```
int toInt(unsigned char* p) {
    return *(p + 0) << 24 | *(p + 1) << 16 | *(p + 2) << 8 | *(p + 3);
}
...
unsigned char arr[4] = {0,0,0,4};
int i = toInt(&arr[0]);
printf("%d", i);
```

should print `4`

Alternatively you might use simple cast:

```
unsigned char arr[4] = {0,0,0,4};
int* i = &arr[0];
printf("%d", *i);
```

but that solution will be depend on endianness. On ideone.com it prints `67108864`.

Comment: For stuff like this, it really should be `unsigned char` though, else there will be trouble with sign-extensions.

Comment: @unwind: Good point indeed, I wasn't thinking about it since I was rather focused on endianness.

Comment: @LihO Thank you! I actually cannot go with the 1st solution since my requirement is to enter a phone number (which starts with the digit 0). If I am gonna use 2nd solution, how am I gonna use the 'strncpy' function? Please simplify your answer ^_^ I'm new to c.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length of each phone number will be the same, you could pad out the front of the number with zeros. e.g. to pad each number out to 10 digits, putting 0's in front when necessary:

```
int d = 123456789;
printf("%d\n", d); // prints 123456789
printf("%010d\n", d); // prints 0123456789

d = 12345678;
printf("%010d\n", d); // prints 0012345678 :-(
```

It's hard to guess more about the requirements without seeing the code. There's lots of examples of formatting with printf, eg: http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output